# Angular 5, HttpClient, environments and interceptors

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-httpclient

I migrated my app to Angular 5 from Angular 4, so I swapped the prev http object to the new httpClient, but I'm having a problem and I don't know if I'm using the proper approach with the environments.

I have multiple environments, let's say:

- customer1.dev.ts
- customer1.prod.ts
- customer2.dev.ts
- customer2.prod.ts

I'm serving the app with the following commands:

- ng serve -dev -e:customer1-dev
- ng serve -prod -e:customer1-prod

Within each envonronment file I have the server address where the AJAX requests have to point to and also other properties. I thought to use an interceptor to add the server address to the request and it is working fine in development but it is not in production, where the interceptor seems to be "jumped" (the console logs are nor printed either, maybe because of the prod env), so all the requests point to localhost:4200, app url.

My service functions use relatives urls, ready to add the domain with the interceptor, and look like:

`getUser(userId: number) {
    return this.http.get("/api/user/${userId}")
        .map(extract)
        .catch(handleError);
}`

I know I can add the server address when I'm calling the function get/post in the service, but I would like to avoid using the same constant over and over. In addition, I can wrap the httpClient in a customized service which gets the server address and attach it calling the proper httpClient function but I would like to know why that fails and if I'm using the environments in a wrong way.

Repo: https://github.com/christiangh/ng5-httpclient-envs-interceptors

In this example I'm making a request to https://httpbin.org/uuid and showing the id retrieved. Both environemnts, customer1-dev and customer2-dev, have a property called domain. With an interceptor I'm adding the domain, https://httpbin.org to a request done to "/uuid", but it only works in dev environment.

Running the app with the following command, it works: ng serve -dev -e=customer1-dev

Running the app with the following command, it doesn't work (because I'm making the request to http://localhost:4200/uuid): ng serve -dev -e=customer1-dev

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's unclear how the things are done in your case. What are the urls are you're using for HttpClient? Are they relative? Should they always belong to same domain and port where the website is hosted? *it is working fine in development but it is not in production* - where is it? The question requires http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry about it. Yes, in the services the url are relatives because the idea is to add the domain with the interceptor. In the service I have something like: this.http.get('/api/user/1'). In development the interceptor adds the domain but it doesn't happen in production.

Comment: Please, provide MCVE that can replicate the issue. Stackblitz or a repo. It's impossible to say if you're using environments incorrectly because it's unknown how you use them.

Comment: I've added a repo in github with an example, thanks a lot for your help: https://github.com/christiangh/ng5-httpclient-envs-interceptors.

Comment: I didn't have a chance to check how it works, but I suspect that this may be a problem for AOT. https://github.com/christiangh/ng5-httpclient-envs-interceptors/blob/master/src/app/shared/interceptors/interceptors.package.ts#L5-L16 Were there no errors on compilation? Try to avoid forEach and define export statically. If this isn't the issue, try also if `ng serve -prod --no-aot -e:customer1-prod` works to make sure that AOT is the problem.

Comment: Hi estus, it was fixed, thanks a million. I'm not sure if the problem was 100% the forEach func, it can be as well, but I think there's also a timing issue. I was declaring (as an empty array) and exporting the array of Interceptors. Later I was adding the interceptors, I also tried it with a let definition instead of const without a loop and it failed as well. So **it is working declaring the array wit the proper data and exporting it at the same time**. There was no error at any place, which is weird. Thanks a lot for your time.